# widening toprule et al. in booktabs

Tags: booktabs

I have two tables side by side.  I want to trick readers into seeing this as one table, by widening the `toprule` command.

In the MWE below I want to join the `toprule` of the cats table to the dogs table, and the same for the bottom rule and mid rules.

[image: Imgur]

This is a sneaky way of entering table data by order of column, rather than by rows.

The MWE is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\toprule
cat\\
cat\\
cat\\
cat\\
cat\\
cat\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\toprule
dog\\
dog\\
dog\\
dog\\
dog\\
dog\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't it just the space after `\end{tabular} `? Add a `%` right after to remove the space

Comment: yes!  but the other guy got the answer first.  sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple to achieve ... just ad % between tables to prevent space between them:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\toprule
cat\\
cat\\
cat\\
cat\\
cat\\
cat\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\toprule
dog\\
dog\\
dog\\
dog\\
dog\\
dog\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes perfect.  I still don't understand the rules of %.......my bad.

Comment: The %  make that `\end{tabular}` is continued without any spaces with `begin{tabular}` in the next editor line. The same result you obtain if you write ` ...\end{tabular}\begin{tabular} ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap the `tabular`s inside a `tabular`. For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}\toprule
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
    cat\\
    cat\\
    cat\\
    cat\\
    cat\\
    cat\\
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}
    dog\\
    dog\\
    dog\\
    dog\\
    dog\\
    dog\\
  \end{tabular}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: nested tables]